# MultiResourceItemReader: Resources dont exist at bean initialization

Tags: spring-batch

Scenario:
Spring Batch job with 2 Steps:

1. Tasklet which downloads csv files (file names unknown before
   runtime) to a directory.
2. Chunk based step with a Reader which needs to read all csv files

Challenge:

Since the file names are unknown, we use `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResources()` to get the `resources`.

The returned resources are always of length 0 since there are no files in the directory at bean initialization.

```
@Bean
Resource[] resources() throws IOException {
    final PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
    final Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("file:" + destinationDir + "/*.csv");
    return resources;
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I second the answer by @Gustavo Passini.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save the names of the files inside the `JobExecutionContext` while in the tasklet step, and then use those names to initialize your resources in the chunk step.

More details at the Spring Batch Docs: [Configuring a Step](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html).

This late binding in Spring Batch is possible due to Step Scope Beans. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/configureStep.html#step-scope).